# Including WPF's namespace in an XSD

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, xsd

We have a custom XML schema that can contain chunks of XAML for defining WPF DataTemplates. I used Visual Studio 2010's "Create Schema" command to generate an XSD based on a sample document that uses our schema.

One of the first lines in the generated schema was this:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"/>
```

However, Visual Studio generates this warning for the line:

> "Imported schema for namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' was not resolved"

Does it need an XSD for Microsoft's `presentation` schema to work? If so, is there anywhere I can download WPF's XSD (I haven't found one with Google, yet). Is there another way around this?

Comment: why don't you use a plain xaml resource dictionary for that?

Comment: @Markus, we want the ability to deliver all the configuration for a client in one file. We've authored the big chunks of DataTemplates in a separate *XIncluded* file, but it's a drag to put all of the one-off templates, styles and other resources in separate files

Answer (score 1):

If you use `xs:import`, and want to use that schema for validation, you will have to provide that (`XAML`) schema.  This can be done in different ways: place file in a known folder, use URL, or load schemas one by one into `.NET` schema set.
Another option is to use xs:any to declare your chunks of XAML, then you will have option to validate it against `XAML` schema or not.